# C# - Efficient initialization of static array where every element is an output of function

Tags: c#, arrays, function, static

Let's say I have  a static function `int foo(int i)` and a static array `long[] bar`, both of which are declared before the main function. I could populate the array right away with elements:  `int[] bar = {foo(0),foo(1),foo(2)...};` **(solution 1)**

While compiler allows me to write this, it doesn't look pretty, especially for huge amount of elements.

Is there a way I could use a for cycle ?

A code such as `for(int i = 0; i<bar.Length;i++) bar[i] = foo(i);`
cannot be written "under" the declaration **(solution 2)**, I need to write the code in the `main` function, **(solution 3)** and I guess I would lose the benefits of using static and pre-initialized stuff.

So, my question is: Is #1 more efficient than #3? Is #2 possible (for cycle outside the main class for initialization)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors):

```
class MyClass
{
    static readonly int[] bar;
    static MyClass()
    {
        bar = new int[10];
        for(int i = 0; i< bar.Length; i++) bar[i] = Foo(i);
    }

    static int Foo(int i) => i + 1;
}
```

Or LINQ with [`Enumerable.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netcore-3.1):

```
class MyClass
{
    static readonly int[] bar = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
        .Select(Foo)
        .ToArray();

    static int Foo(int i) => i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the LINQ methods:

```
static int[] bar = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => foo(i)).ToArray();
```

Note that `foo` must be a static method for this to work, but whichever solution you pick for yout static field will require this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just write a static method that returns the value with which you want to initialise `bar`:

```
static long[] bar = initBar();

static long[] initBar()
{
    int n = 100;
    var result = new long[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        result[i] = foo(i);

    return result;
}
```